# Get Photos from facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook

My account have some photos for sure and they are even public but when I'm trying to get photos from facebook-android way it gives me 200 CODE and empty array.

I have this request:

```
  new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/photos",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                   /* handle the result */
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

And when loggin in I am asking for these permissions with `LoginButton`:

```
 mButtonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        mButtonLogin.setFragment(this);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        final String PERMISSION_EMAIL = "email";
        final String PERMISSION_PUBLIC_PROFILE = "public_profile";
        final String PERMISSION_VIDEO = "user_videos";
        final String PERMISSION_PHOTO = "user_photos";
        permissions.add(PERMISSION_EMAIL);
        permissions.add(PERMISSION_PUBLIC_PROFILE);
        permissions.add(PERMISSION_VIDEO);
        permissions.add(PERMISSION_PHOTO);
        mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions(permissions);
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
        mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, (new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer /{id-of-your-apps} and try your request to see the result.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier it is valid and returns my id and my name

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier by the way in facebook-developer-conolse I have only basic email, public_profile, user_friends.
And I added this user to tester in my facebook console

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Do I need to ask permission in my facebook developer console?

Comment: Not only in the delvelopper console, but in the facebook connexion in your app.